# Le Gall's equivariant KK-theory and twisted equivariant KK-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

I am starting to study Le Gall's equivariant KK-theory and twisted equivariant KK-theory.
Does anyone knows a good reference on this subject?
By the way, I can not access to Journal of K-theory and where can I find the following articles?

Jérôme Chabert and Siegfried Echterhoff: Twisted Equivariant KK-Theory and the Baum–Connes Conjecture for Group Extensions K-theory 23 (2001), 157-200

Le Gall, P. Y.: Théorie de Kasparov équivariante et groupoïdes. I. K-Theory 16 (1999), no. 4, 361-390

Comment: See the question [What happened to online articles published in K-theory (Springer journal)?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136465/what-happened-to-online-articles-published-in-k-theory-springer-journal)

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://www.portico.org/Portico/browse/access/vols.por?journalId=ISSN_09203036

Comment: If you succeed in getting a copy of Le Gall's thesis (probably available from Le Gall), I sort of remember that it is more detailed than the paper...

Comment: Dear Alain, I do not have access to this article via portico.org. Do you? If the case, can you send it to me by email m07kl@math.ku.dk.